# Defining a variable in IF statement (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors

I'm currently learning Java and as part of it I'm trying to make a random number generator.

The project's still at it's early stage but when I was making the error checker component, I faced some issue which I've always been wondering why it doesn't work this way.

Following is the error checker, where it takes in the numberAmount (Amount of random numbers requested by the user) and randomDigit(Largest digits of the random numbers).

I want to make it so it flags when the amount or the digit is too high which could make the app crash.

The following is the code.

```
public static boolean errorCheck(int numberAmount, int numberDigit){

    //int checkAmount = 0;
    //int checkDigits = 0;

    if (numberAmount > 15){
        System.out.println("We can't generate that many numbers!");
        int checkAmount = 1;
    } else if (numberAmount < 0){
        System.out.println("We can't generate negative amount of numbers!");
        int checkAmount = 1;
    } else if (numberAmount == 0) {
        System.out.println("Zero numbers requested");
        int checkAmount = 1;
    } else {
        int checkAmount = 0;
    }

    if (numberDigit > 15){
        System.out.println("We can't generate that many numbers!");
        int checkDigit = 1;
    } else if (numberDigit < 0){
        System.out.println("We can't generate negative amount of numbers!");
        int checkDigit = 1;
    } else if (numberDigit == 0) {
        System.out.println("Zero numbers requested");
        int checkDigit = 1;
    } else {
        int checkDigit = 0;
    }


    if (checkAmount == 1 || checkDigit == 1){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I don't insert the `int checkAmount = 0;` and `int checkDigits = 0;`,  the `last if` statement errors due to no referable variable as such. However if I do include it all the check variables in first and second `if` statement I get errors for pre-existing local variable.

I've tried some fixes and read online but I still don't really understand why I can't define or override variables inside an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that (define variables local to `if` like that) - at least it doesn't make sense. Nor do you need to, just `return true`. Something like,

```
if (numberAmount > 15) {
    System.out.println("We can't generate that many numbers!");
    return true;
} else if (numberAmount < 0) {
    System.out.println("We can't generate negative amount of numbers!");
    return true;
} else if (numberAmount == 0) {
    System.out.println("Zero numbers requested");
    return true;
}
if (numberDigit > 15) {
    System.out.println("We can't generate that many numbers!");
    return true;
} else if (numberDigit < 0) {
    System.out.println("We can't generate negative amount of numbers!");
    return true;
} else if (numberDigit == 0) {
    System.out.println("Zero numbers requested");
    return true;
}
return false;
```

I also notice there is common messaging in this validation; it **could** then be further *simplified* like

```
if (numberAmount > 15 || numberDigit > 15) {
    System.out.println("We can't generate that many numbers!");
    return true;
} else if (numberAmount < 0 || numberDigit < 0) {
    System.out.println("We can't generate negative amount of numbers!");
    return true;
} else if (numberAmount == 0 || numberDigit == 0) {
    System.out.println("Zero numbers requested");
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

> I still don't really understand why I can't define or override variables inside if statement.

You can define them in the `if` statement's controlled block, but any variable definition disappears at the end of the enclosing scope.

You can't override a variable already declared in the same method.

You need this kind of thing:

```
int checkAmount = 0;

if (numberAmount > 15){
    System.out.println("We can't generate that many numbers!");
    checkAmount = 1;
} else // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, variables are defined inside `scopes`.

As you have just experienced you can't use a variable that you have declared in the scope of the if block outside of the if block.

**What is defined inside the scope is not accessible outside the scope.** If you need to **use** a variable inside multiple blocks, you should also **declare** them in a scope common to the blocks you want to use the variable in.

The short explanation is that to comply to the principle of encapsulation, you need to keep your data where you need it, and scopes are a tool in that sense. You declare variable where you need them, and can only use them there.

More about scopes can be found here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/

Your solution of declaring the variables at the beginning of the function is the right way of sharing state beween several blocks, even if, as @ElliottFrisch mentioned, a more seasoned programmer would not write this behavior the way you did.

Answer (score 0):

Elliot answer is right, however if you want to use variables inside if-else blocks you should separate declaration and assignment:

```
int check;
if(...){
    check = 42;
}else{
    // do something else with check
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you declare a variable inside `if` (or any other block), the scope of that variable is limited to that block and hence, compiler will show an error if you try to use it outside of the scope.

Now, if you initialize the variables to `0` outside of `if` constructs, they will be visible to all the `if` constructs as well as remaining method. However, all you need to do is to assign the value and not `re-declare` them inside `if`, e.g.:

```
public static boolean errorCheck(int numberAmount, int numberDigit){

    int checkAmount = 0;
    int checkDigits = 0;

    if (numberAmount > 15){
        System.out.println("We can't generate that many numbers!");
        checkAmount = 1;
    } else if (numberAmount < 0){
        System.out.println("We can't generate negative amount of numbers!");
        checkAmount = 1;
    } else if (numberAmount == 0) {
        System.out.println("Zero numbers requested");
        checkAmount = 1;
    }

    if (numberDigit > 15){
        System.out.println("We can't generate that many numbers!");
        checkDigit = 1;
    } else if (numberDigit < 0){
        System.out.println("We can't generate negative amount of numbers!");
        checkDigit = 1;
    } else if (numberDigit == 0) {
        System.out.println("Zero numbers requested");
        checkDigit = 1;
    }


    return checkAmount == 1 || checkDigit == 1;
}
```

Declaring and Initializing the variables outside `if` and having statements like `int checkAmount = 1;` inside `if` means a variable with same name gets declared twice and hence, compiler shows `pre-existing local variable` error.

Also a couple of points regarding the flow:

- You don't need `else` blocks in the end that asssign `0` values to variables as they are already initialized with `0`
- You can directly return the result of `checkAmount == 1 || checkDigit == 1` instead of writing another set of `if..else` statements

Comment: There is no such thing as an '`if`-block` or 'any other kind of block. A block is a block. It start with `{` and ends with `}`.

Comment: A block preceded by if is an `if` block. Thanks